# Handling Firebase Insufficient Permissions Errors in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How can I handle insufficient permissions errors from firebase? I currently do this:

```
      try {
        DocumentSnapshot doc = await Firestore.instance.collection('SomeCollection').document('SomeDocument').get();
        // Do something
      } catch (error) {
        print('Error: $error');
        // Do something to show user
      }
```

How ever I can't check for only Permission Errors. Sho how can I catch only insufficient permission errors?

Also when should I use `.catchError()`, I tried this:

```
        DocumentSnapshot doc = await Firestore.instance.collection('Some Collection').document('Some Document').get().catchError((onError) {
          // What to do here
        });
```

I doens't seem to really catch a error, because the exception is still thrown

Comment: Any luck!? My firebase falls-back to loading offline data, when user doesn't have sufficient permissions. Despite the error is logged in the console, I can't for the life of me controllably catch the error, to react to it properly!

Answer (score 3):

This is supposed to work

```
 DocumentSnapshot doc = await Firestore.instance.collection('Some Collection').document('Some Document').get().catch((err)=>print(err));
```

Comment: I'm not trying to allow to read the document! My security rules should prevent the document from being read! I just want to catch the insuficient permission exception and only this exception!

Comment: The error looks something like:
`6.0.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at <collection name> failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.`
We want to catch the error, and react to it. Firebase logs the error in the console, but it doesn't throw the error in the code! Instead it falls back to loading offline data, from when user was last logged in.

Comment: @Jonas I just modified the answer add the catch at the end of the query

Answer (score 2):

You can recognize the permission error by the error code (which is 'permission-denied').
If it's a different error, you can throw it, or handle diffrently.

```
try {
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await Firestore.instance.collection('SomeCollection').document('SomeDocument').get();
    // Do something
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'permission-denied') {
      // Do something to show user
    }
    else {
      throw new Error(e); // Or do other things
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Moshe. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Comment: There is no 'error.code' functionality I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Firestore is throwing a generic `NativeError` when a permission error occurs, so, while not ideal, the following message string matching seems to work:

```
try {
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await Firestore.instance.collection('SomeCollection').document('SomeDocument').get();
    // Do something
} catch (error) {
    if (error.toString().contains('code=permission-denied')) {
        // handle permission error
    } else {
        // handle other errors
    }
}
```